# Connect Mininet OVS to physical switch

Tags: virtual, sdn, mininet, openflow, onos

I have two VirtualBox VMs running in my PC, one running a ONOS controller and the other running a Mininet topology with two OVS. Both OVS and physical switch appear in the remote ONOS controller, but i am trying to connect one of the OVS in mininet to a physical ALU-OS (Alcatel OS-6250) switch with no success. I'm just trying to do a simple example to see if it works.
Any idea how?

Please I really could use the help :)

Thanks in advance,
Mariana

Answer (score 0):

You might find [this post and answer](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-to-connect-Physical-Switches-with-Mininet-OVS-switches) from Elisa Rojas useful

**Summary**

Use the statement:

_intf = Intf( intfName, node=switch ), being intfName the host interface (possibly towards the switch. Might need forwarding enabled in Linux) and switch, the mininet switch you want to connect it too.